# Rails Active Model Json serializer: returning has_many record as has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a Active Model JSON Serializer for a model, which has a has_many relation, that I want to include in the JSON response.

I would like the record to be included as `has_one` instead of `has_many` record - to only include the first record:

```
class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :symbol
  has_many :stats
  has_many :body_parts
end
```

Here, `body_parts` should be returned as `has one :body_part`. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return only the first `body_part` and do that only in your serializer response, then better to define it as a method in `PersonSerializer`.

```
class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :symbol
  has_one :body_part, serializer: BodyPartSerializer
  ...
  def body_part
    self.object.body_parts.first
  end
end
```

It assumes that you have a separate serialiser for `BodyPart` model.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as:

```
class Person
  def body_part
    body_parts.first
  end

  # or

  has_one :body_part, -> { order(id: :asc) }
end

class PersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :symbol
  has_many :stats
  has_one :body_part
end
```

In both cases you need to specific what exactly does it mean to be the *first* body part.